# Merge TYPO3 page trees

Tags: typo3

My client has two Intranets, both in TYPO3 and now would like them to be maintained from a single backend and pagetree.  They basically want to merge one intranet with another, the top level page of the second intranet will be somewhere further down the first intranet's page tree.  The second intranet doesn't need to keep its current styles; it can inherit the styles of the first intranet.  This is not a case of creating a domain record and having two-sites-one-tree.

The biggest problems I can see are with things like the file-system, website users, page ids,etc..  and I was wondering if anyone else has had to do this type of thing before and if you have any advice for me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I accept that the only way to do this may be to create a domain record and import the .t3d file into that, to preserve users, etc.  Could someone confirm/deny this?

Comment: Btw: you don't need the domain record for the t3d import. the rest:Try it, it will be bumpy, but ut might do the job. Theoretically, you could also do it on a mysql level, but that would require a thorough analysis of each table, each column... I think you should try it in a dev environment with the import. If it doesnt work out and they have a large budget, you could then still look for customized importing solutions...

Comment: .t3d used to work quite well in the past (TYPO3 4.5 and below with STB or MTB aka TemplaVoila) but if you use some of the modern templeting engines like "fluid pages" etc. you will encounter many problems with loosing nested elements relations, FAL relations and similar. We did it once, then we had to go through the whole imported content and correct relations mentioned above. So for large trees it might be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different ways to do it:

## Copying data manually using SQL

Theoretically it would be possible. I recommend this way only in case you have only data from one table without references to it.

## Creating a migration script

Write a migration script which starts on pages and follows all references as far as you want.
It is quite some work, but it gives you full control of what it does.

## Using the built in import/export functionality (t3d)

I found only an old documentation, but it seems to be basically correct: https://wiki.typo3.org/Faq/copy_parts_of_a_running_TYPO3_system_to_another_server

It is quite tricky because you have to export all relevant data at once, to keep the references. To do it, you need a lot of memory, more than most web servers allow you to use. So you may need to do it on a local copy of your websites while allowing your locally running web server to use a lot of memory.